# Pass variable to external javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a plugin which shows posts from a certain city:

```
<div id='banner-root' style="height: 50px; width: 385px;"></div>
<script src="http://lujanventas.com/plugins/banner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I need to pass the cityID to the external javascript. I'm already getting height and width on the external .js by simply checking the banner-root element.

How do I pass the and ID? Also it would be nice if it was clear that you are passing the cityID

Comment: How are you passing the width and height?

Comment: I get it by checking the div's height and width. What happens if I add an attribute to the script like 'city'. Can I get that with js?

Comment: I don't know. I've read your question three times and I can't make heads or tails of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really pass the width and height to the script according to your comments.. you can use the same style with cityId like so:

```
<div id='banner-root' style="height: 50px; width: 385px;" data-cityId="32"></div>
```

You can  then retrieve it with

```
document.getElementById("banner-root").getAttribute("data-cityId");
```

Answer (score 2):

When I had to do so, I used this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var cityID = x;</script>
<script src="http://lujanventas.com/plugins/banner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then I can access cityID in the banner.js script

**EDIT**

One of Javascript flaws are - everything by default is in global scope.

This means in the example above `cityID` is devined in global **namespace** - `window`. This is great for example when I want to reach this value from `banner.js` but bad by design as missed `var` statement in function body can overwrite global variable.